# Calculate / update a dynamic value in an attribute in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue and I have a hard time trying to figure out how I can update dynamic values.

I have a list of items. The length of all items together is `totalResults`. I would now like to substract values from totalResults and update what is left. So let's say I'd have two lists with a certain length: itemsA.length = 50 and itemsB.length = 25 (in real life I have a lot of lists).

I am trying:

```
<span :count="counttotal(totalResults - itemsA.length)">Count: {{ count }} </span>
```

`{{ count }}` should now be 50, but `totalResults` should be as well.

Next I'm trying to substract B:

```
 <span :count="counttotal(totalResults - itemsB.length)">Count: {{ count }} </span>
```

`{{ count }}` should now be 25, because `totalResults = totalResults - itemsA.length - itemsB.length`.

I am trying this method:

```
methods: {
counttotal(val) {
        this.count = this.count - val;
    }
  }
```

I am getting this error: *you may have an infinite update loop in a component render function*

I can solve it without using a method. But I am pretty sure this is not how it's meant.

```
<span :count="totalResults - itemsA.length - itemsB.length">Count: {{ count }} </span>
<span :count="totalResults - itemsA.length - itemsB.length - itemsC.length">Count: {{ count }} </span>
<span :count="totalResults - itemsA.length - itemsB.length - itemsC.length - itemsD.length">Count: {{ count }} </span>
```

I can set and update totalResults in local storage, but for such a simple task this feels like a workaround.

Any suggestions how I can update `totalResults` each time I am calling the `counttotal` method?

Comment: This is the very reason the computeds exist. The values that are computed from other values, hence the name.

Comment: Thanks you, that makes sense. I've been reading into computed properties (and watchers)  and I can make it work for updating the values once. But when I call (in this case) totalResults again, the value is restored to it's original value again. Do you perhaps have any helpers how I can solve this? I've tried it here: https://shorturl.at/gBK67

Comment: It's a mistake to do side effects in a computed, `return this.total -= this.nr`. Just return the result of a calculation, `return this.total - this.nr`

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. But if I use return `this.total - this.nr`, then `this.total` will always reset to what it initially was. So it will always be 100 - the number, but never cumulative. In this example I would like 100 - 5 = 95 and then 95 - 5 = 90.

Comment: The question doesn't really explain what's going on in your case and how it's supposed to work. I'm not sure on which condition a value is supposed to be cumulative. This looks like XY problem and you discuss a potentially wrong solution. If you need some items with some value to be extracted from be extracted from a total value then it could be something like `return this.totalValue - this.itemValue * this.itemsCount`, and then it's itemsCount that is changed